# Making a small change to a Java protocol buffers object

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I want to make a small change, deep in tree of Java protocol buffer objects.

I can use the `.getBuilder()` method to make a new object that is a clone of an old one with some changes.

When this is done at a deep level, the code becomes ugly:

```
Quux.Builder quuxBuilder = foo.getBar().getBaz().getQuux().toBuilder()
Baz.Builder bazBuilder = foo.getBar().getBaz().toBuilder()
Bar.Builder barBuilder = foo.getBar().toBuilder()
Foo.Builder fooBuilder = foo.toBuilder()

quuxBuilder.setNewThing(newThing);
bazBuilder.setQuux(quuxBuilder);
barBuilder.setBaz(bazBuilder);
fooBuilder.setBar(barBuilder);

Foo newFoo = fooBuilder.build();
```

(This is just 4 levels, I'm routinely dealing with 5-8 levels.)

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Another option is (I think; it's been a while):

```
Foo.Builder fooBuilder = foo.toBuilder();
fooBuilder.getBarBuilder().getBazBuilder().getQuuxBuilder()
    .setNewThing(newThing);
newFoo = fooBuilder.build();
```

Note that this isn't any more efficient; you're still making copies of foo, bar, baz, and quux.

Comment: Thanks, I was really surprised that this worked.  I didn't realise that `fooBuilder.getBarBuilder()` returned a Bar.Builder *in the context of fooBuilder*.  The test suite shows no errors, so it works.  The amount of code still grows linearly with the depth, but at least it's three times smaller.

Comment: If you prefer, you can always keep your objects in `Builder` form long-term rather than immutable message form, and then you can keep a pointer to the particular sub-builder you wish to modify and modify it repeatedly. But watch out for the usual design issues with mutable objects.